# Change the dll dependency on windows

Tags: c++, windows, macos, dll, dependencies

I have to rename some dlls which are used by some xyz.dll. 
For xyz.dll I don't have the source code is there a way to change xyz.dll to point to renamed dlls,

For DYlibs on Mac I used Install_name_tool.
For windows still looking for something, Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You use [Side-By-Side DLL Redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375150%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). Not for the faint of heart.

Comment: The link's content was removed. Perhaps this is an updated one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682600.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For same length new name we can use hack to hex edit the dll...